# "MapiLogonProvider: Network error" with Exchange MAPI Connector

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, evolution, mail

Using Ubuntu 12.04, and Exchange MAPI plugin for Evolution. I have specified the server as an IP address (as found with Google) however when I try and authenticate I get:

"MapiLogonProvider: Network error"

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have eventually found the reason for this. We have a multi-server exchange setup, and its important to use the address of the exchange server in the configuration that has your mail, and not the server that's configured to do outlook web access.